# How to become productive using Vim/Emacs

Tags: python, ruby, linux, vim, emacs

I've been an Eclipse user for the last 3 years or more. I do Java EE (and Spring) development in it and so far I've done 90% of my tasks without having to touch the mouse. Typically my Eclipse setup is as follow:

- Subclipse (or alternatively I use command line)
- m2clipse (Maven Eclipse plugin)
- Data Source Explorer (dealing with SQL)

The typical Eclipse activities I do (and would like to transfer that to Vim/Emacs) are (this is for multi-module/multi-projects/multi-folder source code):

- Refactor (rename method throughout the whole "open project")
- Jump to class implementation
- Search for all usage of a particular class or method
- Updating dependencies (3rd party JARs) via maven pom.xml
- Jump to the 3rd party library implementation (maven can download the source.jar if local repository does not have it, eclipse will bring me to the actual Java code for let say, Hibernate entity manager implementation).
- Write and run unit-test

All of the above activities would not require me to use mouse. There are a few activities where I would need to use a little bit of mouse such as Global Search file

Lately I've been wanting to try development using VMs. The idea here is to create a barebone VM (let's say to use Ubuntu Server) and start coding there or use Putty/SSH.

I have a MacBook Pro 13" which would benefit of using VIM/Emacs or any lightweight editor.

There are 2 major goals:

- Mobility (as in, travelling and coding)
- VM as development environment

Tools I'd like to use are as follow:

- Linux
- Ruby, Python, PHP (and occasionally maybe even Java but definitely not Microsoft .NET)
- Any RDBMS
- Any build/dependency system
- Unit-testing framework

What would you recommend: VIM? Emacs? Others? What about other tools? Gnu Screen, ctags, etc.

Help me build my dream environment: lightweight, productive, easily replicable :)

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2003/4/1/21741/10470 <-- modern day IDE features in emacs

Comment: If you decide to go with emacs, the number one feature I would enable right away is ido-mode: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings . Without ido-mode I found it very difficult to navigate between files and buffers. With ido-mode I prefer it to a tabbed setup. The reason I love emacs (this probably applies to VIM as well) is because after a few years of practice, I've gotten to the point where using my mouse for even 10% of tasks sounds painful. At this point I use my mouse less than .1% of the time I'm in emacs. Even so, my efficiency is still improving.

Answer (score 5):

If you ask a question which involves "vim OR emacs" you will never get an useful answer. It's a religious question, which does not have a correct answer! That said, you should clearly use Vim! ;-)
But seriously: Vim is much more lightweight, so it might better suite the scenario you are describing. Vim can be scripted in different languages and you can find many useful scripts at www.vim.org.
Emacs is "heavier", but Lisp is a very powerful scripting languages. So Emacs is much more of a general tool than just a text editor. IDE functionality (like project management) is something I'm missing from time to time in Vim. There are some scripts to do that, but I don't like them. If you need that, I would go for Emacs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the problem in my question (vim, emacs). But let that be a discussion, whichever can come close to my current Eclipse settings won :).

Comment: By the way, does command-line Emacs do syntax-highlighting?

Comment: @xandross by command-line you mean terminal.? Yes it does

Answer (score 3):

I am an Emacs guy (using vi only to edit configuration files under /etc). I think that with Emacs, you should start it at most daily (and it is very different with `vim`), and you should configure it in your `.emacs` file. For example, I compile using the F12 key, with  `(global-set-key [f12] 'recompile)` in my `.emacs`.

Answer (score 2):

I am vim guy, using it for Perl scripting for around 6 years - and happy with it still - so using it for writing any scripts you said should also be easy & interesting in vim. Once start learning vim - you will definitely like it very much because of the tons of features it has !

I would like to highlight a couple of vim plugins which can give you an IDE feel ! ( but cant make it as real IDE ! )

- [Make Vim as Your Perl IDE Using perl-support.vim Plugin](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/make-vim-as-your-perl-ide-using-perl-supportvim-plugin/)
- [Ctags and Taglist: Convert Vim Editor to Beautiful Source Code Browser for Any Programming Language](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/)
- [Tutorial: Make Vim as Your C/C++ IDE Using c.vim Plugin](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/tutorial-make-vim-as-your-cc-ide-using-cvim-plugin/)

And I believe vim definitely doesn't need mouse !

And you can find a couple of other features explained here in series of articles [vim tips and tricks](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/tag/vi-vim-tips-and-tricks/) ( some of them were written by me. )

Answer (score 1):

For Java development Eclipse has lots of features which you'll miss from Emacs or VIM. However, [there is a project](http://eclim.org/) which makes it possible to access these features from other editors. You may find it useful to make up for missing features.

By the way, if you approach other editors with an Eclipse mindset then almost certainly you will be disappointed, because these editors are built on different philosophies. Their strengths lay elsewhere than the strengths of Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of eclim but that's still runs Eclipse in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Either of those text editors will have a learning curve. That being said I have successfully used emacs to do the following tasks that are in line w/ what you've asked:

1. Write PL/SQL and execute it on an oracle DB all from the editor.
2. Write, Compile, Run java.
3. Edit pom files.
4. Keep a pretty good TODO list in org mode.

You can launch a shell in emacs, and that feature alone does MOST of what you've asked for (SVN, make/ant/mvn/etc).

If you're jumping into one of these editors and hoping for pretty eclipse and vis studio features such as the green junit bar, i'm not sure that they exist. Eclipse' refactor tool works pretty well too and I don't know what is possible in emacs. Though with emacs, I've found that someone has typically written some extension to do what i want, you just need to be able to find it and learn how to use it. I'm an emacs neophyte at best but in scaled down projects I've found it to be pretty efficient and I don't have to take my hands off the keyboard very much.

Disclaimer(java/ee/spring eclipse developer by day that messes around with lua and the love framework using emacs at night)