# Code::Blocks doesn't find my subversion client

Tags: linux, project, codeblocks

I am using a custom Code::Blocks Makefile project, this Makefile uses subversion in it, which is installed in `/opt` and everytime I try to compile my project, I get "Missing Subversion Client", because the Makefile isn't able to find my svn client (normal make from terminal works). I've tried exporting the path in `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/environment`, but both don't work. Code::Blocks is using `/bin/bash -c` to invoke the make command (works too from terminal).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably using `emacs` (with `make`) is simpler. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8001512/841108) & [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17972269/841108) answers. Also, what is your `PATH` ? Does it contains the directory containing `svn` ? Why don't you use your distribution's `svn` ? Can you use `svn` on the command line (try e.g. `svn ls`)??

Comment: Yes, my PATH contains svn, as I've written above, and it works from a bash terminal. My distribution just offers svn 1.7, but I need 1.8 because I share my svn folder with several pcs and those all have 1.8 installed - and no, I don't want to do extra checkouts for each pc. If I add a symlink to /usr/local/bin, then it works, but I don't like that solution.

Comment: I am not at my work computer so I cannot check this, but is there not an "Environment Variables" tab in the Environment settings dialog in Code::Blocks? I have not had any need for that myself, but maybe it can be of use for you?

Comment: Yes that did it, but I had to install codeblocks-contrib first from my packet manager, so I get the Environment Variables Plugin. Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment to the original post as an answer, as per request:

*I am not at my work computer so I cannot check this, but is there not an "Environment Variables" tab in the Environment settings dialog in Code::Blocks? I have not had any need for that myself, but maybe it can be of use for you?*

I am glad that it worked. Sorry about the extra installation though, I did not remember that it was a contributed plugin.